# How do I find a vocabulary ID for use with tokens

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules, tokens

I need the Id for tokens. I know in Drupal 7 it is based on the label but when using tokens for rules the label doesn't work in the identifier. I don't need to find it programmatically. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is actually looking at the database tables...
In MySQL phpmyadmin its under  {Table: taxonomy_vocabulary} and it shows appropriate ID's associated with the label. Another way is through the UI is to navigate to the site's url aliases page.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just pop into the `taxonomy_vocabulary` table in the database and see what `vid` is associated with the correct vocabulary.

For the record if you do need to get it programmatically you can do so like this:

```
$vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('vocab_name');
$vid = $vocab->vid;
```

Comment: In non progammatically, I meant without code... just looking at the UI...

Comment: I don't think there's a way through the UI (vocabs are referenced by their machine name as you've said), but using PHPMyadmin to inspect the database involves zero programming

Comment: thnx ... much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do this on a dev server for which I didn't have any mysql or phpmyadmin access. SO for the record, here's a few alternatives:

One option is to temporarily create a view of taxonomy terms filtered by the vocabulary. If you enable view query display in views settings, you should see the vocabulary id in the query.

Or, in the same view .. if you expose a filter of vocabularies, the vid will be visible if you inspect the html of the select option.

If you have Devel Themer module enabled, I'm sure you will find the vid if you investigate the arguments of templates on the taxonomy page.